# How are Minor Improvement and Occupation cards meant to be selected for play?

Tags: agricola

I'm reasonably experienced playing Agricola - but the family friendly version only, because the people I've played with find the game complicated enough as it is.

I understand how the minor improvements and occupations are supposed to be used; at the start of the game each player will have seven occupations and seven minor improvements, which they'll play through out the game.

The question is - how do I decide which deck (E, I, K) to use, and how do I select nPlayers * 7 occupations and minor improvements from it?

From what I've seen, the purpose of the different decks is to provide differing levels of complexity to game, the E deck being more suitable for beginners and the K deck for very experienced players.

I also see there are various ways to distribute the initial seven cards, a draft commonly being used, [as suggested in this question.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/house-rule-for-minor-improvement-occupation-distribution)

Say I am playing with a draft, with three players. Do I just randomly select 21 minor improvements from the E deck?

Can someone please provide a step by step guide to setting up the game, from deciding which deck to use, to selecting the cards for draft/mulligan and then drafting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decks you use are completely at the discretion of the players.  I like to use all the decks I own.  Some people like to use certain decks.  Some people like to ensure a particular distribution of cards from each deck, but I find that tedious.  Here's how I set things up:

- Set up the game board normally.
- Shuffle all Minor Improvements together from all decks.
- Remove all Occupations that carry a number greater than the number of players in the game (this number appears in a colored square and is either 1+, 3+ or 4+).
- Shuffle all remaining Occupations together from all decks.
- Randomly deal out 7 (or more) Occupations to each player.
- Randomly deal out 7 (or more) Minor Improvements to each player.

(The next two steps are the drafting steps, which you can skip if you want to.)

- Each player chooses on Occupation and one Minor Improvement to keep, then passes the rest of their dealt cards to the person on their left/right.
- Repeat the previous step until all cards have been chosen.
- If you chose to deal more than 7 Occs/Minors, each player discards until they have 7 each.
- Play the game.

Comment: Also, when you deal out occupations, make sure that you remove any that carry a number greater than the number of players in the game (this number appears in a coloured circle and is either 1+, 3+ or 4+).

Comment: Great thank you - That's what I thought was the case, just wasn't sure.